# Biber typesetting fails

Tags: biblatex, compiling, biber

On MacOs X running updated mactex packages, when I compile my biber file I get this error:

```
data source /var/folders/yf/y69gwrx12kj2jtzrs78vg2vm0000gn/T/par-67696f6e61/cache-    23e542f078c05cf97a78083ff4d628bc746d389d/inc/lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml not found in .
Compilation failed in require at Biber/Utils.pm line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Biber/Utils.pm line 20.
Compilation failed in require at Biber/Internals.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Biber/Internals.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 22) line 2.
...propagated at /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.14.1/base.pm line 94.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Biber.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at script/biber-darwin line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script/biber-darwin line 20.
```

Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: It's very easy to solve it, actually. `:)` Remove the problematic folder (the one with `/var/folders/yf/y69gw...`)  and run `biber` again. `:)`

Comment: As Paulo said, this is usually due to interrupting biber on its first run (of a new version) so that it doesn't unpack properly. Just delete this folder:

/var/folders/yf/y69gwrx12kj2jtzrs78vg2vm0000gn/T/par-67696f6e61

and run biber again once without interrupting it (just with no arguments for example) to make sure it unpacks correctly.

Comment: I had different folders (no yf) under /var/folders/, but I just ran a sudo rm -R * and it solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I also found this answer helpful... and the exact answer from @PLK sorted me out. So, I don't think it's too localized - though perhaps the wording of the question is overly localized.

Comment: 12 upvotes — please reopen and accept Paulo's solution?