# Suddenly I cannot compile my bibTex files anymore (Biber, TeXmaker, MacTeX)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, texmaker, biber

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Engines of Tex-Editors and Biber/Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47553/engines-of-tex-editors-and-biber-biblatex)

I am currently working on a bunch of little assignments for university. Everything was fine until yesterday:

All of a sudden when compiling the BibTeX I get an error and can therefore not create my bibliography. I thought it was a problem with some entries in my `.bib` file. After a lot of very desperate trying to fix this error I thought I should try to compile the bib of other files I have. I tried and I failed.

So I guess I have some major problem. Unfortunately I do not remember changing anything which would have caused this problem to occur.

In my texmaker preferences it says "/usr/texbin/biber" % for BibTeX and in the header of my TeX file I have `\usepackage[sorting=none, backend=biber]{biblatex}`

The error I get is:

```
FATAL - Error loading data source package 'Biber::Input::file::bibtex': data source /var/folders/GT/GTSW-4xWG4e7gPwCb+0Sxk+++TI/-Tmp-/par-user/cache-fe147f467ff57455f519af2e054cbfc46578602e//inc/lib/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.dcf not found in .
Compilation failed in require at (eval 79) line 2.
```

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What you are describing looks correct.  What error do you get?  If it looks like the one here [Biber typesetting fails](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84973/2693) then follow the directions in the comments there.

Comment: unfortunately I don't get the same error.I added the error message to my post.

Comment: try with the same solution (remove the folder/directory)

Comment: Which file would you delete? I tried `rm -r /var/folders/GT/GTSW-4xWG4e7gPwCb+0Sxk+++TI/-Tmp-/par-usr/cache-fe147f467ff57455f519af2e054cbfc46578602e//inc/lib/Biber/Input/file/`
but i still get the same error.

Comment: @Zwähnia Try `rm -fr /var/folders/GT/GTSW-4xWG4e7gPwCb+0Sxk+++TI/-Tmp-/par-usr/cache-fe147f467ff57455‌​f519af2e054cbfc46578602e`, that is up to the "double slash".

Comment: Thank you very much, deleting everything starting at the `//` worked!